# Bigquery date conversion from string to date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a field string field in BigQuery with values like "Jan 27 2009 12:00AM".

How can I convert "Jan 27 2009 12:00AM" to "2009-01-27" in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select 
    parse_timestamp("%b %e %Y %R%p", "Jan 27 2009 12:00AM" )
```

More detail can be found here on the parse_timestamp function:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp

Comment: Terrific, please consider upvoting and marking correct

Comment: I have upvoted but I don't have enough reputation.  Thanks again.